# Popup at boot, warning about unspecified "problem"

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot, oneplus-one

[image: popup warning]

A few days ago my device (oneplus one with cyanogen) started showing this popup at boot, is there a way to diagnose this unspecified "problem"?

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/development/fix-build-prop-variety-fix-aka-contact-t3133347/page7

Have a look at this.
It's the same issue,but with a different device(nexus 9).
My advice for you would be to ask(post) in the above page, about whether or not you can safely flash the given fix without bricking your device.
If not, then would it be possible for them to modify the fix(zip file), and make it suitable for your oneplus one.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will reflash it eventually (with LineageOS) but I'd like to investigate before, for the sake of curiosity.